# C# find object in list using a object field

Tags: c#, list, linq

So i have the following `List`:

```
List<AttackStyle> AttackStyles = new List<AttackStyle>();
```

With the following types of objects:

```
AttackStyle lStyle = new AttackStyle();
lStyle.Name = "Attack Achilles";
lStyle.ParameterID = 0;
lStyle.Forward = Vector3.forward;
lStyle.HorizontalFOA = 70f;
lStyle.VerticalFOA = 40f;
lStyle.DamageModifier = 1f;
lStyle.ActionStyleAlias = "Jump";
lStyle.IsInterruptible = true;

AttackStyles.Add(lStyle);
```

Now i wish to find the field `ParameterID` where the `ActionStyleAlias` is equal to a value (for instance `"Jump"`)

This is for a Unity application so the search / find needs to be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straight solution is:

```
 var pId = AttackStyles.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.ActionStyleAlias == "Jump")?.ParameterID
```

But if you want to get a better performance, it would be better, to index the most useful property which you want. Therefore, construct a dictionary on the most useful fields to get a better performance in time. For example:

```
   var styles = new Dictionary<string, AttackStyle>();
   styles.Add("Jump", new AttackStyle() 
                      {
                           Name = "Attack Achilles",
                           ParameterID = 0,
                           Forward = Vector3.forward,
                           HorizontalFOA = 70f,
                           VerticalFOA = 40f,
                           DamageModifier = 1f,
                           ActionStyleAlias = "Jump",
                           IsInterruptible = true
                      });
```

Then, find the object by this:

```
var pId = styles["Jump"].ParamterId;
```

or if it might be null:

```
if(styles.Keys.Contains("Jump"))
    var pId = styles["Jump"].ParamterId;
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of such?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen the constructed index on keys would be B-Index. So, there is no need to find each time the list in a linear order (O(N)). You can find the result in O(log(n)) order. Also, there is a better data structures such as `trie` which you can find your result in O(1).

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = AttackStyles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ActionStyleAlias == "Jump").ParameterID;
```

Comment: you mean `x => x.ActionStyleAlias == "Jump"`

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad yes, was typing with javascript in mind :P

Comment: This will throw exception if doesn't find the `AttackStyle` with `ActionStyleAlias=="Jump"` condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
var param = AttackStyles.First(x => x.ActionStyleAlias.Equals(value)).ParameterID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's return first `ParameterID` if there's the required item in the collection; `-1` otherwise:

```
 var result = AttackStyles
   .Where(item => item.ActionStyleAlias == "Jump")
   .Select(item => item.ParameterID)
   .DefaultIfEmpty(-1)
   .First();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try extension methods. Also you should consider null cases:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static int? FindParameterId(this List<AttackStyle> values, string actionStyleAlias)
    {
        return values.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ActionStyleAlias == actionStyleAlias)?.ParameterID;
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
List<AttackStyle> attackStyles = new List<AttackStyle>();
var parameterId = attackStyles.FindParameterId("Jump");
```